# Facing Issue : Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm using `useReducer`, `Context` and `Provider` in my app but I'm facing this issue please anyone faced this issue so please let me know the solution for it

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at App.js:20., 
>       in _default (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
>       in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
>   - node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:26:24 in error
>   - node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:188:36 in warningWithoutStack
>   - node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:603:32 in warning
>   - node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1730:14 in createElementWithValidation
>   * App.js:20:5 in _default
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9473:27
>   in renderWithHooks
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11994:6
>   in mountIndeterminateComponent
>   - ... 18 more stack frames from framework internals
>
> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at App.js:20., 
>       in _default (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
>       in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
>   - node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:26:24 in error
>   - node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:188:36 in warningWithoutStack
>   - node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:603:32 in warning
>   - node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1730:14 in createElementWithValidation
>   * App.js:20:5 in _default
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9473:27
>   in renderWithHooks
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11994:6
>   in mountIndeterminateComponent
>   - ... 21 more stack frames from framework internals
>
> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.
>
> Check the render method of `_default`.
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5716:10
>   in createFiberFromTypeAndProps
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5744:4
>   in createFiberFromElement
>   - ... 22 more stack frames from framework internals
>
> Warning: %s: Error boundaries should implement
>   getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to
>   display an error message or fallback UI., RootErrorBoundary
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
>   - node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:26:24 in error
>   - ... 28 more stack frames from framework internals

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import IndexScreen from './src/screens/IndexScreen';
import { Provider } from './src/context/BlogContext';

const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Index: IndexScreen
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Index',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    title: 'Blogs'
  }
});

const App = createAppContainer(navigator);

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

BlogContext.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

    export default (reducer, actions, initialState) => {
         const Context = React.createContext();

         const Provider = ({ children }) => {
             const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

             const boundActions = {};
             for(let key in actions){
                 boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
             }

             return(
                 <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
                     {children}
                 </Context.Provider>
             );
         }

         return(Context, Provider);

    };
```

Comment: Probably an import issue. Check all your imports as if they are named or default.

Comment: what is Provider in your case?

Comment: @Safeer I upload my provider class please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue regarding `BlogContext`. You are not using it correctly. 
You export it as default a function while in `App.js`, you use a named import.

`BlogContext` should be like this:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

    export default (reducer, actions, initialState) => {
         const Context = React.createContext();

         const Provider = ({ children }) => {
             const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

             const boundActions = {};
             for(let key in actions){
                 boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
             }

             return(
                 <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
                     {children}
                 </Context.Provider>
             );
         }

         //return an object with two keys
         return {Context, Provider};

    };
```

and `App.js` should use that accordingly:

```
import blogContext from './src/context/BlogContext';
/**
 ...code ... 
**/
//here you create your provider by calling the function imported from BlogContext
//with the expected arguments
const { Provider } = blogContext(reducer, actions, initialState)

/**

**/

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```